# Manage multiple Store cloudkit container

Tags: swift, core-data, swiftui, cloudkit

i have a todolist app sync with icloud, but I want to set a default folder that will be only local, kind of "inbox". I've read this apple documentation https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/mirroring_a_core_data_store_with_cloudkit/setting_up_core_data_with_cloudkit

But i really don't understand how can i select the local container instead of cloud container when i create an entity on my code.

this is an example code of what i'm doing creating new entity :

```
        let newarchiovio = Archivio(context: self.moc)
        newarchiovio.id = UUID()
        newarchiovio.nome = "inbox"
        newarchiovio.icona = "tray"
        newarchiovio.colore = "purple"
        newarchiovio.data = "1"
        newarchiovio.favorite = true

        try? self.moc.save()
```

Right now i'm using only default container sync with cloud. Can anyone make me an example of how can i manually select containers when i saving an entity? 
thanks!

Comment: I think you have to use the context to assign it to the correct store.  See [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsmanagedobjectcontext/1506436-assign).

Comment: ah ok, like : self.moc.assing(obj,CKContainer(identifier: "container name here"))?

Answer (score 0):

You can use different containers as in here:

```
CKContainer(identifier: "container name here")
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, so can you write a pratical example?

Comment: No problem. What do you exactly want me to write? If you have more specific questions regarding CoreData or CloudKit you can always ask a new question.

Comment: ok, if i have to create a new obj like the previus example, then i have to save it with save() method of moc, but in this case is saving in generic container right? i don't understand what kind of method i have to use to assign that obj to a specific container. Can you write an example where you create a new object and save it in a specific container? thanks (i'm using swiftui)